# Слэши и ковычки после использования stringify

Tags: javascript, json

Есть подобный скрипт:

```
var output = {
    lol: [
      {name: "hahaha"}
    ]
  };
  console.log(output);
  output = JSON.stringify(output);
  console.log(output);
```

в итоге получаем

[image: результат]

почему он вставил слэши и кавычки там, где не надо?

Comment: В FF 38.0.1 через FireBug у меня выводит без бэкслешов

Comment: получается такая трабла только в хроме?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/MJDYv/70/ - 3 раза вызывается `stringify`. в консоль выводится сам объект + еще по разу на каждый `stringify`. В итоге в консоли я вижу объект, объект, строку, строку с бэкслешами. Это озадачивает..

Comment: Довольно забавно получается, когда вставляю свой код в jsfiddle, то всё работает отлично, но стоит закинуть в мой файл, всё становится плачевно как на картинке

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Может сразу сделать валидный JSON

```
var output = {
    lol: {name: "hahaha"}
  };
  console.log(output);
  output = JSON.stringify(output);
  console.log(output);
```

Правда я незнаю что за переменная `name`